# perform a groupby on dataframe created from a groupby

Tags: pandas, sum, grouping, dtype

Thought this would be somewhat easy but once again - not the case --- for me.

I have created a groupby and saved as a dataframe.  Now I wish to perform a groupby on that dataframe, but I have errors everytime I try to do counts on the columns that were summed in the previous groupby. Below is the dataframe from the first groupby:

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
employee                           int64
Date1                     datetime64[ns]
Duration           sum           float64
RoundedInMinutes   sum             int64
RoundedOutMinutes  sum             int64
```

I can do group by on the employee and even a lambda function using Date1. However, I am unable to perform a lambda function on the Duration. There is a Key error on Duration.  Any of the columns with sum in the dtype create an error.

Code to created first groupby:

```
groupedByEmployeeShift = df.groupby(['employee', 'Date1']).agg({'Duration': ['sum'], 'RoundedInMinutes': ['sum'], 'RoundedOutMinutes': ['sum']}).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  employee      Date1 Duration RoundedInMinutes RoundedOutMinutes
                           sum              sum               sum
0   102209 2015-06-27     5.87                0                 0
1   102209 2015-07-23     8.17                0                 0
2   102209 2015-08-15     8.00                0                 0
3   102209 2016-01-30     8.23                2                 0
4   102209 2016-08-13     8.25                4                 0
5   102209 2017-01-28     8.00                1                 0
6   102209 2017-08-19     8.02                5                 0
7   102209 2018-02-10     8.00                2                 0
8   102209 2018-08-18     8.10                0                 0
9   102209 2019-02-09     7.93                1                 0
```

Code to run against this groupby dataframe:

```
shiftStats=groupedByEmployeeShift.groupby('employee')['Duration'].apply(lambda x: (x> 0).sum()).reset_index(name='OT_Shifts')
```

I know this is something simple - but I just can't figure it out.

Your help is super appreciated.

Comment: Can you remove the multi index and try the groupby after. `groupedByEmployeeShift.columns = groupedByEmployeeShift.columns.droplevel(0)`

Comment: Why not `groupedByEmployeeShift.loc[ groupedByEmployeeShift['Duration'].gt(0) ].groupby('employee')['Duration'].sum()` ?

Comment: You should really post the expected output, I assumed you need that sum I commented, but your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Jeeze. Not obvious but simple to fix.  The "sum" is on a second row of the header for the dataframe. Just used the code below to remove it and all works now.

```
groupedByEmployeeShift.columns = groupedByEmployeeShift.columns.droplevel(-1)
```